# CQ5.3 Servlet Unavailable ( and Servlet Resolver Paths Configuration (5.3 v 5.6))

Tags: java, servlets, aem

Historically I've only ever used CQ 5.6, but am now working on a project using 5.3 and am failing to get a servlet registered and accessible. When I try to hit the servlet (with and without and extension) I get the following *INFO* line in the error log:

```
GET /bin/TestServlet.json HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet service: Resource /bin/TestServlet.json not found
```

I can build the bundle containing the servlet, deploy it using the maven-sling-plugin, and the bundle ends up in the console as 'active', but the servlet isn't available. I'm using the following in my class file to define the servlet:

```
@SlingServlet(paths = {"/bin/TestServlet"}, methods = {"GET"}, extensions = {"json"}, metatype = true)
@Properties({
  @Property(name = "service.name", value = "com.something.servlets.TestServlet", propertyPrivate = true),
  @Property(name = "service.description", value= "Test servlet I am trying to geet working", propertyPrivate = true),
  @Property(name = "service.vendor", value = "something", propertyPrivate = true)
})
```

Please note that I have also tried that alternative using the `@Component(.......)` and `@Service(value=Servlet.class)` annotations

Looking to see if the problem is configuration based (thinking /bin was blocked) I went back to 5.6.1 to compare configuration and noticed that the config for ***Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler*** differs between 5.3 and 5.6.

In 5.6 you can configure the servletresolver.paths which (if I understand things correctly) opens up paths for execution, but this is not present in 5.3

So:

1. Does the configuration for servletresolver.paths exist in 5.3?
2. Can I even register a servlet like this in 5.3?
3. If the answer to 2 is 'no', can you point me at an example/tutorial on how to do this in 5.3 (Docs and tutorials are thin on the ground for this version)?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT (resolution)**:
It seems to be down to versions in the POM (and *possibly* plugin config). May only have been one culprit, but I simply don't have time to try all permutations. If I get time to try I'll add an edit.

Successful versions:
maven-bundle-plugin - v2.4.0
maven-scr-plugin - v1.13.0
maven-sling-plugin - v2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in CQ5.3 you can use 'JCR resolver' to check servlet mapping. 
Go To

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/jcrresolver
```

And enter path to your servlet in 'Configuration Test'. 
e.g.

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/TestServlet
```

resolve result should mapping to your servlet
for example

```
ServletResource, servlet=com.test.impl.HelloJSONServlet, path=/bin/TestServlet
```

Also there is code snippet which works in CQ5.3

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false, label = "Hello JSON Servlet")
@Service(serviceFactory = false, value = javax.servlet.Servlet.class)
@Properties(value = {
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET" }),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = { "json" }),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = {"/bin/TestServlet"})

})
public class HelloJSONServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write("{ \"hello\" : \""+username+"\" }");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @victar (very much appreciated). I've basically copied your code and it still does not work for me. Any chance you could post the POM you used so I can see the dependency versions - grasping at straws here. P.S. It doesn't even resolve in the configuration test

Comment: It may take time to separate this code as maven project.
Before I start, can you, please, do following test
1)go to
`http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles` 
and check your bundle installed and status active
2)go to
`http://localhost:4502/system/console/components`
and check your component active there
`Default State enabled
Activation immediate
Service Type service
Services javax.servlet.Servlet
component.name = com.test.impl.HelloJSONServlet
service.pid = com.test.impl.HelloJSONServlet
sling.servlet.extensions = json
sling.servlet.methods = GET
sling.servlet.paths = [/bin/TestServlet]`

Comment: Hi @Victar, The bundle is there and active, but the component is not there.

Comment: stop and start your bundle. 
And check error log
`\crx-quickstart\logs\error.log`
if everything correct you should see there 
`Service [com.test.impl.HelloJSONServlet,<service_id>] ServiceEvent REGISTERED`
or see any errors.

Also you can check your bundle
 `http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/<bundle_id>`
there should be link to your service
 `http://localhost:4502/system/console/services/<service_id>`

Comment: Hi @Victar The only thing appearing in the logs is 'Stopped' and 'started' for the bundle. No other information. Also when I check the bundle detail there is no link to the service. The package containing the servlet is listed in the 'exported packages' list, and they are again listed in the Manifest headers list, but no service link. It looks like everything is set up to work, but I'm obviously missing something. I'm assuming the log level for the entries in the log file you mention are INFO and not a lower level like DEBUG?

Comment: I think something wrong with OSGI-INF\com.test.impl.HelloJSONServlet.xml in your bundle I've shared my example you can check it and play with sources https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_xqFl5_7k0pNC1sSURXdDJrd00/

Comment: Thanks @Victar Much appreciated. I'll download it and take a look.

Comment: `https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_xqFl5_7k0peFMyUjJzZU1WV3M` this link should be valid

Comment: Thanks @Victar, your version works. There are subtle differences in the configurations and versions in your POM. I'll move these over to mine. Many thanks.